# Define functions

Tags: function-construction

I want to know how to define functions. I dont mean a function in the sense f[x_]:=x^2 for example, but I mean a function which takes parameters and returns something. Like in C++, you can define such a function as

```
int function(int parameter){
   //do something
   return something;
}
```

and then in the main function we can call this function. How can we do something like this in Mathematica? If I look for function on google, all I get is the function in the sense f[x_]:=x^2.

Edit:

I want to do the following for example. I want the input and output to be polynomials in some variables, and the function is a differential operator. For example, $p(x_1,...,x_n)=x_1^2+...+x_n^2$ and the differential operator is for example $\sum_{i=1}^nx_{n+1-i}\partial x_i$ where $\partial x_i$ takes the derivative of the polynomial with respect to $x_i$.

Comment: `f[x_] := x^2` takes one parameter and returns one result.  In this respect it behaves just like the C function you showed.  I don't understand your question.  Perhaps read through this: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsAndProgramsOverview.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working out the example from the edit:

```
expr = x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 + x4^2 + x5^2;
```

Extract the variables:

```
var = Variables @ expr
```

> {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}

Then compute the sum:

```
Sum[var[[Length @ var + 1 - i]] D[expr, var[[i]]], {i, 1, Length @ var}]
```

> 2 x3^2 + 4 x2 x4 + 4 x1 x5

Those intermediate steps can be gathered into a single function:

```
operator[input_] := Block[{var},
  var = Variables @ input;
  Sum[var[[Length @ var + 1 - i]] D[input, var[[i]]], {i, 1, Length @ var}]
  ]

operator[expr]
```

> 2 x3^2 + 4 x2 x4 + 4 x1 x5

---

In case of expressions like

```
a x1^2 + x2^2 + b x3^2 + 2 x4^2 + c x5^2
```

also `a, b, c` will be treated as variables by `Variables`. If some symbols are to be treated as parameters, it's probably simplest and safest to manually set which symbols are variables and which are not, like in [Sumit's answer below](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129837/22013). Also, `Variables` works well on polynomials, but fails e.g. with this:

```
Variables @ Sin[x]
```

> {Sin[x]}

Comment: In the function operator[input_] in the second line you write var = Variables @ expr; Dont you have to replace expr with input? Because I want also to input other polynomials

Comment: Yup, good call. Edited.

Comment: I have one more question: I made a table of all the variables I am working with, it is a little different than in the example above. I have variables $p_{i,j}$ where $i$ and $j$ run through some index. I used vars = Table[Subscript[p, i, j], {i, 1, 7}, {j, 1, 3}] to define these variables in a table. How can I use these variables in the Block? I couldnt adjust your code to work with variables in a table. In this case I would have differential operator which is written as a double sum over $i$ and $j$.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this

```
func[poly_, var__] := Module[{n}, n = Length[var]; 
                      Sum[var[[n + 1 - i]] D[poly, var[[i]]], {i, 1, n}]]

func[a x1^2 + b x2^3, {x1, x2}]
```

> 2 a x1 x2 + 3 b x1 x2^2